# With bookshelf.js, how do I update a model record atomically?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, bookshelf.js

I have a one-to-many relationship with a JOB model and many TASK(s).  I have a route for individual tasks, where I fetch the TASK model for display, and some data from its JOB model.  When I request a TASK, I need to update the locked and a user_id fields, so I can lock the task and show who has it locked, so other users can't access that task view.  Therefore, I need to be guaranteed the task has locked=0, and instantly update that field with a time stamp.

My current router code is:

```
var route_task = function(req, res, next) {
   new Model.Task({id: req.params.id}).fetch(withRelated: ['jobs']})
      .then(function(task) {
         if (!task) {
            res.status(404);
            res.render('404_tpl');
            return;
         }
         if (task.get('locked') !== 0) {
            res.status(403);
            res.render('403_tpl', {title: '403 - Access Denied - Task is locked'});
            return;
         }
         else {
            /* I would update it here, but there's a slim */
            /* chance someone else can come in and select */
            /* the task. */
         }

         /* .. I set some res.locals vals from my task here .. */

         var jobs = task.related('jobs');
         jobs.fetch().then(function(job) {
            /* .. I set some res.local vals here from my jobs .. */

            switch (task.get('task_type')) {
               case 0:
                  res.render('task_alpha_tpl');
                  break;

               /* ... */
            }
         });
      })
}
```

When I hit my router for a particular task ID, I pretty much want to select * where tasks.id = id and locked = 0, and then set locked with the current timestamp, but, I need to be able to determine if the record with that ID didn't exist, or if it did, but was just locked.

I hope this makes sense.  I'm coming from the C and PHP world, so I'm slowly learning async programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it in a transaction I guess if you want the value not to change, I don't think you should use semaphore or other stuff in the client side to simulate a critical section or something in that mindset.

Comment: Yeah, this would be all server-side.  At this point, I think I should update the record where user_id = 0, locked = 0, and id = 0, and if that succeeds, then I know the time, user id, and of course my task ID to select back to display in my template.  I'm going to try that.

Comment: ok just do it in a transaction so you know that nobody will tap into your series of query, you can find it in the documentation

Comment: OK.  I may need help doing it async (promises).

Comment: That's for sure, every call to the orm needs to be async and it will be a promise XD

Answer (score 0):

The general purpose solution for this problem is to run something in the form of:

```
UPDATE task SET locked=1,user=? WHERE job=? AND locked=0
```

And then check that the update actually modified at least one row.
If you're doing that in node.js, then I would do something like:

```
Tasks.forge().where({job: req.param('code'), locked:0}).save({locked:1},{method:"update"});
```